# Generating initial population in genetic algorithm

Tags: r, genetic-algorithm, population

I tried to initialize my initial population using a binary matrix. To add diversity to the population, the number of `1's` for each chromosome range from two to five.

However, the initial population that I obtain lacks diversity. My population size is 100, but 97 of them have five `1's` in them. Below is my implementation in R, using the GA package:

```
library(GA)

set.seed(1)

initial_population <- function(object) {
    ## generating a 10 x 10 matrix (population)
    init <- t(replicate(object@popSize, {i <- sample(2:5, 1); sample(c(rep(1, i), rep(0, object@nBits - i)))}))

    return(init)
}

g2<- ga(type = "binary", 
    population = initial_population, 
    fitness = DBI2, 
    selection = ga_rwSelection,
    ## intentionally disable crossover and mutation for testing
    pcrossover = 0,
    pmutation = 0,
    ## popSize is small to illustrate my problem
    popSize = 10, 
    nBits = 10)
```

Checking the initial population `g2@population`, the chromosomes appeared to be the same.

[image: Initial population showing all same chromosomes]

Is there a mistake in my code? Or are there better alternatives to generate a population that is diverse?

Comment: I do not know much about `ga` package, but are you sure `g2@population` represent the initial population? To me looks like the final one, because even with the default `population` setting I get similar results

Comment: Thanks for raising a good point! Is there a way to check the initial population?

Comment: Uhm not sure about a specific `ga` way, but running your `initial_population` function, passing `popSize` and `nBits` instead of a ga objects gives me a valid (and varied) result